# I need vba code to locate the coordinates of centroid of a shape

Tags: excel, vba

As mentioned in the title. I drew a polyline in CAD using excel VBA I need to locate the coordinates of the polyline's centroid I don't know the proper code.

```
Sub Drawline()       
    Dim point(0 To 7) As Double 

    Dim myapp As Object 
    Dim AcadDwg As AcadDocument 
    Dim B As Double 

    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER 
    Set myapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application") 

ERRORHANDLER: 
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        Err.Clear
        Set myapp = CreateObject("Autocad.Application") 
    End If

    myapp.Visible = True 
    Set AcadDwg = myapp.ActiveDocument 

    'Now Excel VBA = CAD VBA with same coding 
    Dim line As AcadLWPolyline 
    point(0) = 0: point(1) = 0 
    point(2) = 1: point(3) = 1 
    point(4) = 2: point(5) = 0 
    point(6) = 0: point(7) = 0 
    Set line = AcadDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(point)

    Dim t As AcadLayer 
    Set t = AcadDwg.Layers.Add("pline")
    line.ConstantWidth = 0.1 
    B = line.Area 
    MsgBox B      
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the original code you used to create it will help people here understand what you did and how to get the coordinates you want, it is very difficult to help when we don't know how you did it...

Comment: Is the shape consistent or is it geometrically fluid?  If it's consistent, we can help.  If its not though, it's not really suitable to use VBA as there are just too many formula variations.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: I appreciate your responses thank you , I took a screenshot of the code as I couldn't write it properly here >>
http://www.mediafire.com/file/o2541cp44x49uwc/inquiry.jpg you can view it not necessary to download it ... I'm just collecting the needed to begin coding my program with the least info. missing .... Thanks and sorry to bother you

Comment: the shape is a simple 2D polyline , not necessary to be a rectangle or triangle they are easy I meant complex shapes

Comment: @Roushdy Please always add the code to your original question ([edit]) **as text** formatted as text block. Otherwise people here cannot modify it and post an answer (see [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I made it , sorry I'm new to this website I didn't know how to do so